# can anyone tell me about the model (skipgram/ CBOW ) used by Gensim?

Tags: python, nlp, semantics, gensim, word2vec

word2vec uses either of the model for distributed representation of words. I was checking out the codes of gensim but it is not defined about the model used by gensim .

Comment: It uses CBOW by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the gensim documentation:](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec)

> `sg` defines the training algorithm. By default (`sg=0`), CBOW is used. Otherwise (`sg=1`), skip-gram is employed.